# How to filter result in Json file using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, json, rest

I get bit confused about how to display error if a title is not found in json file.Here is a code that I tried. Everything is working perfectly but when I use if(searchName != todo.name) then result displayed only error whether the name is write or wrong.Please help me.I ll appreciate.

```
const list = document.getElementById('list');
const userAction = async (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const searchName = document.getElementById('searchName').value.trim();
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(todos => {
    todos.forEach((todo) => {
      if(searchName == todo.title){
        const li = document.createElement('li'); 
        li.textContent = `${todo.userId} ${todo.id} ${todo.title} ${todo.completed}`;
        list.appendChild(li);
      } else if(searchName != todo.title)
{
 const li = document.createElement('li');
   list.textContent = `Search Result not found`;
 list.appendChild(li);

}
    });
  })
}

<form method="POST">
 <input type="text" id="searchName" class="form-control" placeholder="Lorem name">
<button  onclick="userAction(event)" class="search-icon"><img src="images/icon.png" alt="submit"></button>
  </form>

<ul id="list">

</ul>
```

Comment: you don't need `if(searchName != todo.title)` its implied in first if condition

Comment: use `todos.filter(element => element.contain(searchName));` is better

Comment: @MahdyAslamy Can you please show me how to use this one in my code.Thnaks

Comment: @JacekRojek not working still showing only error but not the result.Even if I write the correct title.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.

```js
const list = document.getElementById('list');
const userAction = async (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const searchName = document
    .getElementById('searchName').value.trim();

  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(todos => {
      let result = todos
        .filter((todo) =>
          todo.title.includes(searchName));

      while (list.firstChild) {
        list.removeChild(list.firstChild);
      }
      
      if (result.length > 0) {
         result.forEach(todo => {
           const li = document.createElement('li'); 
           li.textContent = `${todo.userId} ${todo.id} ${todo.title} ${todo.completed}`;
           list.appendChild(li);
         });
      } else {
        // not found.
      }
  });
}
```

```html
<form method="POST">
 <input type="text" id="searchName" class="form-control" placeholder="Lorem name">
<button  onclick="userAction(event)" class="search-icon"><img src="images/icon.png" alt="submit"></button>
  </form>

<ul id="list">

</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I just tried ur code but its showing error.Can you please try it and share code snippet that would be very useful for me.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
const td = todos
  .filter(element => element.contain(searchName))
  .map((todo) => {
        const li = document.createElement('li'); 
        li.textContent = `${todo.userId} ${todo.id} ${todo.title} ${todo.completed}`;
        list.appendChild(li);
  })
if(td.length <= 0) {
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  list.textContent = `Search Result not found`;
  list.appendChild(li);
}
```

or more fancy method:

```
const td = todos
  .filter(element => element.contain(searchName))
  .map((todo) => `${todo.userId} ${todo.id} ${todo.title} ${todo.completed}`)
if(td.length <= 0) {
    td[0] = `Search Result not found`
}
td.forEach(t => list.append(`<li> ${t}</li>`))
```